# Website slow : my fault or the host?

Tags: performance, hosting-recommendation

My website is really slow, and I have no idea why : I read some articles about how to save time and so on but it still takes up to 7s to load a page.

Here is the report : https://tools.pingdom.com/#5c4199b967800000
I don't really understand what it says, so I'm open to suggestions to gain some time.

If it is due to the host, have you any recommandation in Europe for another host in Europe ?
Thank you very much

Comment: Each one of the results has a clickable down arrow with more details. Do you have trouble understanding each one of those? Really?

Comment: @tripleee well for example the second one which takes 3s, says that it is waiting for a response from https://iwu.sgy.mybluehost.me/ , but can it be because of the plugins I installed on wordpress, or is it just the host ?

Comment: Someone (you or your host) will have to look at the server to work out what's taking those three seconds. It could be slow database access, or running out of memory (if you have a small VM or you're running the database server on the same VM), or too many database queries from lots of plugins that do lots of work, or something else. I'd start by looking at `top` or `htop` on your server whilst making a few requests, and watch the memory and CPU usage of your server / php processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if ypu fix your host fast problem, I suggest to use a cache plugin like Wp Fastest Cache or Wp Super Cache. Exactly Wp fastest cache plugin is great. We use it on our website, you can take a look from this **[link](https://tisort.web.tr)**

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
I did optimization on the server side before reaching help and use cache plugin, image compression and so on. Turned out it was a host problem, I duplicated the website from bluehost to cloudways and limitlesshost, and it turned out that the page was slighly faster with limitlesshost but almost instantaneous with cloudways